# Select specific value XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I select just the "fail" value using XPath?

```
<Properties>
  <Property Descriptor="100">1377349460.298</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="24000">fail</Property>
</Properties>
<Properties>
  <Property Descriptor="100">1377349462.298</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="101">1</Property>
  <Property Descriptor="24000">pass</Property>
</Properties>
```

I tried `Property[@Value="fail"]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What language? What framework are you using to scrape the XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the `Property` element containing the string `fail` use:

```
Property[.='fail']
```

or

```
Property[text()='fail']
```

as Babai correctly suggest.

`.` means 'the current node', `text()` means 'the first text within the current node', so the expressions mean 'select an element called `Property` containing `fail`')

This assumes that the current node is right above the `Property` element, if you want to find `Property` in any level below the current node use:

```
//Property[.='fail']
```

In XPath a non-empty node-set is considered `true` when used in a test - so the above XPath is (in a sense) already a test if there are any `Property` nodes anywhere containing `fail`.

If you want to count how many nodes `Property` nodes at any level contain `fail` use:

count(//Property[.='fail'])

Comment: Really interesting the //Property[.='fail'].Does it get the values for ANY level? So if I want to know if there is a value "fail" in a row of 100 values for example can I use an IF statement? How it'd look like (I'm sorry for the stupid questions but I'm new in XML/XPATH)

Comment: @Dalek You could do this way now - `//Property[.='fail'][position(.) => 1 and position(.) < 101]`

Comment: @Babai How could I test if there's more than 0 "fail" values in the properties? For example TRUE when one of the Properties are "fail" and FALSE when both properties are "pass"

Comment: @Dalek post another question..You will get help from someone.Don't ask in comment please.. :)

Comment: @babai I'm sorry. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I expanded my answer somewhat

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as below also :-

```
//Property[text()='fail']
```